# I can't use the error I caught in laravel by Throw middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, throw

I have created a handler called UnprocessableEntityException for error handling in Laravel and it works fine for the api.php part, but not for web.php. what should I do? I can't show it in the views because it is used in middleware, do I need to convert the data returned from all throw handlers? Or do you know another way?

Comment: show your code ...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue might be related to the fact that the handler is being used in middleware. One option could be to modify the handler so that it also returns a response that can be used in views. Alternatively, you could create a separate handler specifically for web.php that handles the error in a way that allows it to be displayed in the views. Another approach could be to modify your middleware to catch the UnprocessableEntityException and handle it in a way that allows it to be displayed in the views. Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to provide a definitive solution, but hopefully these ideas will point you in the right direction.